# Delete column in excel file using ExcelJS

Tags: javascript, excel, exceljs

So i have an excel file and I want to delete a specific column ( for example : column I ).

I searched in the documentation and I can't find anything that indicates how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
worksheet.spliceColumns(start, count, ...inserts)
```

which is somehow similar to javascript [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function.

so if you want to delete the whole **B column**

```
worksheet.spliceColumns(2, 1)
```